# Link into full div - html and css

Tags: html, css

**Some text**

```
.sliderPart {   
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sliderPart a {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;
    height: 100%;
    font: 1.3em  Arial, Sans-serif;
}
```

How can I make my link clickable for all div-area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the link outside the div. You can make an anchor tag act similarly to a div. Like you're doing in the css you posted.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing is to remove the div altogether:

```
<a href="#computers" class="sliderPart">
   <strong>Some text</strong>
</a>

a.sliderPart {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".trigger").click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

..you'd also need to give `cursor: pointer` to the clickable element.

Answer (score 0):

For dropdown lists, I use the following method a lot...

If you're not opposed to using scripts, you can make the div itself a proxy of sorts, so that if you click anywhere on the div, the first link within that div is subsequently clicked automatically.

```
$(".sliderPart").bind("click", function(){
  $("a:first", this).trigger("click");
});
```

Of course you would want to update your styles for the div when you mouse over it to indicate the entire thing is clickable.