# CSS link to cover div block

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Link into full div - html and css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516552/link-into-full-div-html-and-css)

I'm trying to construct CSS where the `<a>` tag covers an entire `<div>` block, so that anywhere on the `<div>` can be clicked.

Here's how the final div should look (image is 64×64px):

[image]

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div>
        <img src="" alt=""/>
        <h3><a>On The Beach</a> <span class="exclusive">Exclusive</span></h3>
        <span class="details">Save 10% off all package holidays</span>
    </div>
```

Any CSS guru's help?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks - Html5 <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be you can write like this:

```
<a href="#">
        <img src="" alt=""/>
        <h3><span>On The Beach</span> <span class="exclusive">Exclusive</span></h3>
        <span class="details">Save 10% off all package holidays</span>
    </a>
```

**CSS**

```
a{
 display:block;
}
```

*Note: as per html5 you can define block elements inside `<a>` tag*

Comment: Thanks sandeep, I didn't know that. Makes things a whole lot easier in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you want have to anchor cover the whole block, your HTML should reflect that. While block-level anchors are a fresh idea from XHTML2/HTML5, they are working in nearly all modern browsers (even IE 7).

Just enclose all the DIV's contents with the anchor:

```
<div>
    <a href="#nohref">
        <img src="" alt="" />
        <h3>On The Beach <span class="exclusive">Exclusive</span></h3>
        <span class="details">Save 10% off all package holidays</span>
    </a>
</div>


div a {
    display: block;
}
```

See also: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

> Shiny, but not new
>
> What’s also very interesting about this technique is that actually this isn’t new: you can do it now. […] That’s one of the interesting things about HTML 5—it documents existing browser behaviour. As the browsers already handle wrapping links around block-level elements, and there is an obvious use-case, there was no reason to artificially keep the structure as invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap with anchor tag

```
 <div>
 <a href="#" class="cont-wrap-link">
 <img src="" alt=""/>
 <h3><a>On The Beach</a> <span class="exclusive">Exclusive</span></h3>
 <span class="details">Save 10% off all package holidays</span>
 <a>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div a.cont-wrap-link
{padding:0px; margin:0px;
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check out this** [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-an-anchor-ever-correct)

**Remember**: Ensure that the structure of the document still makes sense when CSS is not present.

**Update**

You can Achieve this using **HTML5**. Check [this](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as your doctype is HTML5 you can wrap the entire block in an anchor:

```
<a href="yourURL">
<div>
        <img src="" alt=""/>
        <h3><a>On The Beach</a> <span class="exclusive">Exclusive</span></h3>
        <span class="details">Save 10% off all package holidays</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

No need for any JS :)

Answer (score 0):

While this probably could be done with somewhat hacky CSS I believe JS (jQuery) is easier in this case:

```
$('#the-div').click(function () {
    $(this).find('a').eq(0).click();
});
```

Or something like:

```
var theDiv = document.getElementByID('the-div');

theDiv.onclick = function () {
    window.location = theDiv.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
};
```

Comment: You mean JS with the jQuery library.

Comment: Since it's so common nowadays I sometimes forget to mention that I'm using jQuery. But yes, I meant with jQuery. Updated answer with plain JS solution as well.

Comment: A link is a link is a link. Hyperlinks are the part of a hypertext that are defining the WWW. It's the web's most basic feature and you are ruining every chance to work with them properly (e.g. open a link in a new tab; copying the anchor, …) by suggesting wild and dirty JavaScript hacks to achieve what HTML is already made for.

Comment: Well the link would still be there so it's not like I'm suggesting _only_ relying on JS. Although I agree that wrapping everything in the link is better. As you probably know this wasn't valid until recently however.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with feeela here. Unless a function is specically targeted as a javascript enhancement all links should works as links.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I understand you there, but absolutely, if you're using an HTML5 doctype or don't care about validation then the best solution is definitely to wrap everything in a link.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add `onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;"` to your div tag.